# GHUnit jump to error in code

Tags: ios, unit-testing, assertion, gh-unit

Does GHUnit (iOS) support jumping to the assertion in code that caused a test to fail?

I am evaluating GHUnit and think I have previously got this working, but now it does not. So do I remember wrong or is it something wrong with my setup? It is working perfectly in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a breakpoint in module libobjc.A.dylib for symbol objc_exception_throw.

If this will not help, try the CoreFoundation module for symbol -[NSException raise].

I just don't remember which one of them works for GHUnit...

Comment: I assume this is a workaround? I am doing an evaluation of OCUnit and GHUnit and are more interested in their standard behavior.

Comment: Their standart befaiviour is actualy to catch the exception so they'll be able to evaluate all the tests and not to stop on first exception. I'm guessing that you are upgraded your xCode as in newer versions it doesn't stop on every exception. It also may be the issue of changing compiler from gdb to llvm. Anyway, it will do the work for you. (and by the way may help you to track exceptions in working code also, not only in unit test)